# Plone- ComponentLookUpError is preventing me from deleting Plone site?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I'm trying to delete a Plone site I am testing.  However, when I delete it, I get an error.

From the console:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 540, in manage_delObjects
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 391, in _delObject
  Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.event, line 32, in objectEventNotify
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 101, in dispatchObjectWillBeMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 101, in dispatchObjectWillBeMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 101, in dispatchObjectWillBeMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 101, in dispatchObjectWillBeMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 101, in dispatchObjectWillBeMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 271, in handleContentishEvent
  Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 76, in unindexObject
  Module Products.CMFCore.CatalogTool, line 280, in unindexObject
  Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 354, in uncatalog_object
  Module Products.ZCatalog.ZCatalog, line 508, in uncatalog_object
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 383, in uncatalogObject
  Module Products.PluginIndexes.common.UnIndex, line 286, in unindex_object
  Module Products.PluginIndexes.UUIDIndex.UUIDIndex, line 98, in removeForwardIndexEntry
  Module z3c.relationfield.relation, line 79, in __cmp__
  Module z3c.relationfield.relation, line 82, in _sort_key
  Module z3c.relationfield.relation, line 31, in from_path
  Module plone.app.relationfield.monkey, line 14, in get_from_object
  Module z3c.relationfield.relation, line 110, in _object
  Module zope.component._api, line 169, in getUtility
ComponentLookupError: (<InterfaceClass zope.intid.interfaces.IIntIds>, '')
```

The page just displays:

```
 (<InterfaceClass zope.intid.interfaces.IIntIds>, '')
```

I do use IIntIds in an event subscriber and I am wondering maybe if this could be the problem.

When a object of a particular content type transitions, another object of another content type is created and I "get" a relation value from the created object using the IIntIds utility.  The RelationValue is appended to the relatedItems of the object transitioning.
The object created has relatedItems as well and I get the relation value of the object transitioning and append it to the created object's relatedItems.

In configure.zcml:

```
  <subscriber
  for="my.product.myobject.MyObject          
       Products.DCWorkflow.interfaces.IAfterTransitionEvent" 
  handler=".events.myObjectTransitioned" />
```

In events.py:

```
def myObjectTransitioned(obj,event):

    ....
    action = event.status['complete']
    if action == 'activate':
        .....
        try:
            new_obj = api.content.create(container=OtherObjs,portal_type='my.object.anotherobject',
               title=a_concat_title, id=a_concat_title)
            int_ids = getUtility(IIntIds)

            obj.relatedItems.append(RelationValue(int_ids.getId(new_obj)))
            new_obj.relatedItems.append(RelationValue(int_ids.getId(obj)))

            obj.reindexObject()
            new_obj.reindexObject()
        except:
            print "failed creation"
```

I came across a similar question that was asked and one of the answers mentioned not having plone.app.relationfield or plone.app.intId installed.  I have plone.app.relationfield (RelationValue) and plone.app.intId (plone.app.intid: install utility).

I'm basically doing this so that the new_obj can get information from obj (transitioned object), and visa versa, by conveniently calling to_object.  However, I'm guessing this is causing this error and I should use a back reference for new_obj getting information from obj?

Comment: I apologize if I am not providing enough detail or if this is a duplicated question, but I am unfortunately lost.

Comment: You may have better luck posting questions on our forum, https://community.plone.org (more eyeballs), though I will post a link on the forum to your question here.

Comment: unfortunately there's not enough information to help you; I think you may have some event subscriber that is being called when you try to delete the site; you should try to locate the offending event and skip its ZCML registration; restart the instance and try again.

Comment: @T.KimNguyen Thank you for posting the link to the question.  I appreciate it.  I'll try posting there.

Comment: @hvelarde Thank you for your response.  I'm thinking that's what it might be.  If I find out, I'll share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What basically prevents you from deleting your site are the events that are triggered everytime (that run your mentioned troublesome code). To prevent this behavior, I can suggest doing the following:

```
$ cd {buildout-dir}
$ bin/zopepy
> from transaction import commit
> app._delObject('Plone', suppress_events=True)
> commit()
```

In general it is not recommended to do this for objects within a Plone site, as this would for example also prevent the portal_catalog from updating and cause other side effects. But as you delete the site as a whole, it does not matter.

Comment: Thank you for you response.  I appreciate you taking the time.  

I ended up finding out that there was another issue in another product regarding a relation value breaking.

But I appreciate you sharing that.  Its a more convenient alternative to deleting the data.fs for me.